# Server 2008 R2 - GPO To Remove 'Menu Bar'

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, terminal-server

I'm making a lock down policy for my 2008 R2 terminal server, and am wondering if anyone knows how to remove the 'Menu Bar' from explorer. It's the bar that has 'File, Edit, Views, Tools, Help' in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPMC, User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Explorer.  From there disable "Display the menu bar in Windows Explorer".  Note that users can still access the menu bar if they press the 'Alt' Key.  If you want to disable that, I don't have anything to help with that.